# How to share final .ipa file with clients to upload into itunes connect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I am a developer and I am making an app for my client.
I have indie developer account so During testing period I am using client's UDID to build ipa file so they can test on their iOS devices.

Now client will distribute final ipa file into itunes connect.
so What are the different legal solutions for this?

Assume that they have indie developer account too and client is non-technical so they don't want to mess with xcode or source code.

And in future I will do the same for other clients too.

Answer (score 1):

In order to submit an app to iTunesConnect, it has to be signed with a valid distribution certificate and provisioning profile that match the developer account they are submitted to. That means that someone (whether it's you or your client) needs to create an appID, a distribution certificate and a matching app store provisioning profile that you will then use in Xcode to sign the ipa that will be submitted to the store.

Since your client isn't a technical person and you will most likely be able to do that process much quicker and more efficiently than he/she will, the best solution would be for your client to simply give you the credentials to the developer account and for you to perform these steps there. If that's not an option, and your client has a company account (and not a personal account), he/she can give you access to their account by adding you to their development team - that way, you'll still be able to perform the necessary actions on the account, without having the admin's personal credentials.

As for the submission itself, once you have a signed archive, you can either submit it directly via Xcode or you can send the signed ipa to the client, and he/she can submit it via Application Loader from their admin credentials. But, you will still have to sign it with valid certificate/profile from the right developer account.

I hope this makes sense and makes things a bit clearer. Good luck.